Finding the mean in c++ with a sorted vector. Why do I need to subtract 1 from size in the odd case?
To preface, I am trying to learn C++ through "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++, 3rd Edition", and this is Exercise 4 provided in Chapter 3.
This is the code I have:
void print_mean(vector<double> vec, string measure)
{
    size_t size = vec.size(); 

    if (size == 0) //check if empty
    {
        cout << "Input an empty vector";
        return;
    }
    else if (size == 1)
    {
        cout << "\nMedian " << measure << " is " << vec[0];
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if (size % 2 == 0) //if even
        {
            size_t truncated_index = size / 2;
            double average = (vec[truncated_index] + vec[truncated_index - 1]) / 2.0;
            cout << "\nThe Median " << measure << " is " << average;
        }
        else //if odd
            cout << "\nMedian " << measure << " is " << vec[(size - 1) / 2];
    }
}

void exer4()
{
    //read distances into vector
    vector<double> distances;
    for (double temp; cin >> temp;)
        distances.push_back(temp);

    //sort
    ranges::sort(distances);

    //print sum
    double sum = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < distances.size(); i++)
    {
        sum += distances[i];
    }
    cout << "\nThe sum of all distances: " << sum;

    //print largest, smallest
    if (distances.size() != 0)
    {
        cout << "\nThe smallest distance is " << distances[0];
        cout << "\nThe largest distance is " << distances[distances.size() - 1];
    }

    //print mean
    print_mean(distances, "distance");
}


int main() 
{
    //exer2();
    //exer3();
    exer4();

}

This code seems to work, but I don't understand why I need to subtract 1 from the size variable in the odd case:
else //if odd
    cout << "\nMedian " << measure << " is " << vec[(size - 1) / 2];

It seems like if the size was odd, for example 7, then dividing it by 2 should give 3.5 and I should be left with 3, which is the middle of 0-6.

Your analysis is correct. Why did you write it with that - 1 if you don't believe it's needed?

Minor point: neither of those return statements in print_mean is needed. And personally, I'd continue the else if ladder and not put that last if in its own block.

vec[size / 2] would work just as well. It so happens that, for an odd positive value, size/2 == (size-1)/2, because  integral division truncates towards zero. By way of example, 5/2 == 4/2 == 2 . I suppose the author of the code just wanted to make it explicit; to not force the reader to reason through finer points of C++ integral division.

Pedantic note: you are using the terms mean and median interchangeably. They are not. They are 2 different things. Your code is finding the median. Using the term mean here is misleading and can confuse simpleminded folk like, uh, me.

Terry Pratchett on the character of Carrot: "He has a simple mind. People tend to confuse that with stupidity." (roughly, not verbatim; from Anguas musing, if I am not mistaken). I like that concept, like many in his work.

void print_mean(vector<double> vec, string measure) --> void print_mean(const std::vector<double>& vec, string measure) -- The vector is not being changed in the function, so the vector should be passed by const reference, not by value.   Passing by-value incurs a temporary copy, which slows the code down. If the book you're using is a good one, then it would have shown passing objects by reference.

Apart from conflating mean and median, you're incorrectly assuming floating point division, in saying that 7/2 gives 3.5.    You're doing integer division so rounding is always toward zero.   So the -1 when size is odd is unnecessary (it doesn't change anything)  -   for positive odd values, (size - 1)/2 == size/2.    For example, 7/2 gives 3, not 3.5 and (7-1)/2 gives 6/2 which is 3.   The only thing being changed by subtracting 1 from an odd value is to make the previous even value, and dividing that by 2.

The even case is special:

a b c d has a median (b+c)/2 - of the middle 2 element at indices 1 and 2.

Odd, say with size 5 just picks the middle element at index 2:

a b c d e has a median c.

To come from size to index they coded index = (size - 1) / 2.
Perfect true and understandable (5 to 2).
However you are right and they could have written index = size / 2 because of integer division (5 / 2 == 2).
One can however imagine that such a solution in an exercise requires explaining this integer division. Think of the questions this would raise from newbies.
Note that the total else could be generalized (without even/odd) as;
double median = (vec[(size - 1)/2] + vec[size / 2]) / 2.0;


Taking the average of 2 elements for the even case is just a convention, it's not the only way of handling it.  And it does have the disadvantage of giving you a real number median when given a list of integers.

@MarkRansom thanks, a usefull clarification. The terminology as I know (non-native English): below median (even), at median (odd), above median (even).
